# Excel VBA to SQL - Query table VS ADO

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, ado

I have a question regarding pros and cons or difference in functionality of importing data to Excel using VBA query table and ADO.

I've compared both methods and I do not see too much efficiency difference between those two as I imported about 30k rows and about 20 columns and it took both methods about 3 minutes.

The most obvious differnce is that Query inserts an excel table inside spreadsheet and ADO does not.

But do You know about any other issues/pros/cons?

Background:
Spreadsheet will be configured to import data from the same SQL table but selecting data from different periods (months). Each time it will be less than 1k rows. Spreadsheet should be elastic, so that anybody from the company will be able to use it on their own computer.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions :)

Comment: Windows and Mac, or just Windows?

Comment: Just Windows but different vesrions 7 to 10 and different architectures x86 and x64 - same with MS Office 2007-2016 and x86, x64.

Comment: Query table might be safer - I have no experience with mixed Excel 32bit/64bit deployments

Comment: Safer in terms of compability/reliability?

Comment: It's a "built-in" feature, so I'd expect it to be more consistent across different platforms, but that's just an assumption: I have no evidence to back that up.

Comment: Using ADO runs risks of referencing different versions of the ADO library across versions of office/windows.

Comment: I am using ADO with late binding, so I do not have to add reference to library - Excel takes care of it on its own.